# Type coercion in JavaScript , how is the conversion done?

Tags: javascript

This is because the equality operator == does type coercion, meaning that the interpreter implicitly tries to convert the values before comparing.

[Looked into this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1)

but, 0 == '' , I dont understand why it returns true. Can any one explain? what is 0 converted to ? and what is '' converted to to return true ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When *abstractly* comparing a string and a number, regardless of the order, the [string will be converted `ToNumber()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) for the comparison:

```
4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String,
   return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
   return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
```

In the case of `0 == ""`, `ToNumber("")` results in `0`, which is exactly the other value:

```
0 == ""  // becomes...
0 == 0   // becomes...
true
```

Note: You can see how the  [internal-only`ToNumber()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) handles different values by using the [`Number()` constructor without `new`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.1):

```
console.log(Number(""))
// 0
```